# Show all contacts

Tags: custom-fields, menu

I am trying to create a navigation menu item (under 'contacts') that displays a list of all contacts.

I found an old thread that suggest to create a new menu item and use the following URL: civicrm/contact/search&force=1&qfKey=0

This generates the following full URL/link:

http://localhost/xxxxxx/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contact/search_force_1_qfKey_0

When I do this however it just loads the CiviCRM admin home page.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that will work, just need one alteration, change the first ampersand to a question mark: 
`civicrm/contact/search?force=1&qfKey=0`

Just tested it out on http://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ and it works great.